# Making a <tr> table row keyboard accessible for navigation when pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I have a table in which I am presenting data to the user and they have the ability upon clicking on a table row that it will take them to a detailed page based on what they clicked.

Currently I am able to get focus on the row but I wanted to know is there a way of making the row accessible so that the user will navigate to the detailed page when pressing enter as they did with a click?

Does `(click)` only works with mouse clicks - is there something like `(enter)` that could do the same thing?

Here is how my table looks:

```
<table *ngIf="rosterList" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr tabindex="0" *ngFor="let user of roster" (click)="onuserSelected(user)">
            <td>
                {{user.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
               <a (click)="userClicked(user)">{{user.Name}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{user.classTitle}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd be concerned assistive tech would be thrown off by a table row that acts as a link, when it contains cells that contain links.

Comment: if you know what row is focused, you can have a global event listener for `keyPress`, read the `keycode`, and if it's 13 (enter key) then run `onuserSelected(focused_user)`